# producing a installable python module using hg archive vs wheel

Tags: python, mercurial, package, python-wheel

I wonder if I would release my python modules using:

1. **hg archive** and **sourceforge** download
2. **wheel** and a **PyPy** hosting

I was using 1 for years now, but I think the right pythonic way to do is 2

Any piece of advice ?

wheel requires pip, wheel, setuptools... it looks quite complicated for a simple module compared to a simple tar extract and a setup.py install.
on the other hand, it seems the pip/wheel is now being somewhat required?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually *quite simple*.

And yes Python [wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) are the recommended approach going forward as well as the use of [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install and maintain installations of packages.

**Example:** (*packaging your module*)

1. Create a `setup.py`:
2. Install wheel
3. Register and Upload this to PyPi

---

**Example:**

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="my description",
    long_description=open("README.rst", "r").read(),
    author="You",
    author_email="Your Email Address",
    packages=find_packages("."),
)
```

**Note:** This is a *bare minimum* example of a `setup.py`. See [Writing the setup script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) for more infirmation about other "metadata" you can include.

Install [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) so you can build wheels:

```
$ pip install wheel
```

Register and Upload your proejct/module to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi):

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel register upload
```

I recommend you have a read of [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/)

---

Also if you do not have [pip]1[] installed you can *eaisly* do so using the bootstrap script (*as long as you also have Python isntalled*):

```
$ python <(curl -q -o https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
```

Comment: I've tried the **wheel install** command, is that something close to **pip install** or **python setup.py install** because I cannot find out the way to specify a **--prefix** dir (I do not want virtualenv) ?

Comment: @Marcvs I'm farid if you insinst on **NOT** using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) you're jsut going to end in a world of pain. You can specify however ``--user`` and ``--root`` options to ``pip``. But please use virtualenv!

Comment: yes virtualenv is quite useful, but I see my developpers coding in their own env and gathering code integration is my "world of pain". I've spend too much hours rewriting codes using brand new incompatible versions. On the other way, I'm trying to change to wheel to manage these incompatibilities so...

Comment: The use of virtualenv is *meant* to help alleviate incompatibilities between versions of packages. What issues are you having?

Comment: exemple: one uses cython 0.22 in his env, another 0.17 which is baseline for released package. Incompatiblities are to be managed by hand (AFAIK). Then we force people to stay on v0.17 and we do not allow local envs. That's straightforward, so far that's the easiest solution I've found...